# How to turn off automatic install of Apple Watch extension?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

We are looking at adding an Apple Watch extension for our current iOS app. One of the requirements is that the watch extension not to be automatically installed on the user's watch upon update of the iOS app. For security reasons we would like to ask the user to specifically enable the extension to be on the watch.

I know there is a setting to enable/disable individual watch extensions, but I don't know if and how can be programmatically changed. The third answer on this thread leads me to think that it is possible https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7026092 but extensive googling didn't give me any clear answer.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't control this, as it is up the the user. The user can set their phone to automatically install Watch Apps when they are downloaded or do it manually. The user sets the preference in the My Watch app under Genereal>Automatic Downloads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is beyond your control. **Only the user can choose** whether to automatically install new `WatchKit` apps on their Watch automatically or not, and I personally think this is the best solution.

It seems to me like you should reconsider *why* it's necessary for your app to force the user to manually install the `WatchKit` app through the iOS app. This shouldn't be necessary.

However if it is, Apple will definitely update `WatchKit` at WWDC now and they *might* introduce the option to let the parent app decide whether to automatically install the `WatchKit` app *or not*. These are just pure speculations though, and you can **follow WWDC [here](http://techcrunch.com/2015/06/08/join-our-wwdc-2015-keynote-live-blog-at-10-am-pt/)**.

If not, you can always employ some sort of **workaround**. For example set up a `shared app group` and `shared user defaults`. When the main app launches you can ask whether to activate the `WatchKit` app, and set a `bool` in the `shared user defaults`. When the `WatchKit` app launches, check this `bool` and if the user hasn't said yes yet, simply cover up the `interface` with a `label` that tells the user to go to the main app first.